# I want to release an eBook on the app store ? What is the procedure /

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store

I have an eBook in ePub format and want to release **as an app** on the Apple App Store ?
How can I go about it? 
Does apple need the ISBN code? 
Can I just integrate one ebook in the app?

Comment: This might be relevant [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Comment: Yes, it's not a question for SO since it's not directly related to programming. Also you can't submit books to the App Store anymore. They should be submitted to the iBooks Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some requirements though but help is available.You'll need to have:

- ISBN numbers for the books you want to distribute
- the ability to deliver the book in EPUB format
- the book pass [EpubCheck 1.0.5+](http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/)
- a US Tax ID (sorry world, this is only open to the US at this point)
- an iTunes account backed up by a credit card

**If you can't provide listed requirment**

> If you don't know how to get an ISBN
>   number or potentially want to get paid
>   faster, Apple suggests that you use an
>   Apple-approved aggregator. These are
>   firms that have a financial
>   arrangement with Apple and can provide
>   a number of services at what seems to
>   be a reasonable cost. Each aggregator
>   delivers a different set of services

Here is one of top **Approved Aggregators**

http://apple.libredigital.com/

you can find others [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=Apple%20approved%20aggregator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it into an app, then you need to develop an ebook reader if sorts. In that case, Apple does not need the ISBN. You likely can integrate just one book, but remember to include enough functionality so that Apple will not consider your "app" to be of little entertainment value.

Alternatively, you can [apply for the iBook store](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/apply).